# PHP standard input?

Tags: php, file-io, stdin

I know PHP is usually used for web development, where there *is* no standard input, but PHP claims to be usable as a general-purpose scripting language, if you do follow it's funky web-based conventions. I know that PHP prints to `stdout` (or whatever you want to call it) with `print` and `echo`, which is simple enough, but I'm wondering how a PHP script might get input from `stdin` (specifically with `fgetc()`, but any input function is good), or is this even possible?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It is possible to read the `stdin` by creating a file handle to `php://stdin` and then read from it with `fgets()` for a line for example (or, as you already stated, `fgetc()` for a single character):

```
<?php
$f = fopen( 'php://stdin', 'r' );

while( $line = fgets( $f ) ) {
  echo $line;
}

fclose( $f );
?>
```

Comment: You could also use the predefined constant STDIN instead of opening it manually: $line = fgets(STDIN);

Comment: STDIN did not work for me, but 'php://stdin', 'r' did.  Using PHP 5.2.9-2 (cli) (built: Apr  9 2009 08:23:19) on Vista.

Comment: @EricJ., Weird, how did that even happen? Did you `fclose` `STDIN`?

Comment: This bails at the first falsy line.

Answer (score 48):

Reading from **STDIN** is [recommended way](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

```
<?php
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets(STDIN))) {
   echo $line;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 26):

To avoid having to mess around with filehandles, use `file_get_contents()` and `php://stdin`:

```
$ echo 'Hello, World!' | php -r 'echo file_get_contents("php://stdin");'
Hello, World!
```

(If you're reading a truly huge amount of data from `stdin` you might want to use the filehandle approach, but this should be good for many megabytes.)

Comment: That will block the script and the web server indefinitely! Use `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead, that works.

Answer (score 18):

A simple method is

```
$var = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

Comment: Also we may use ` $contents = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Comment: But why trim()?

Comment: it's always better to trim the whitespaces and new lines, you may skip it if you don't want to.

Comment: Warning: Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Looks like `STDIN` only works in console usage, not with a POST body.

Answer (score 13):

Grab it all in one shot:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
echo $contents;
```

Comment: That will block the script and the web server indefinitely! Use `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead, that works.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/fopen) on `php://stdin`:

```
$f = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
```

Answer (score 6):

This also works:

```
$data = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, you may also use the following:

```
$in = fopen(STDIN, "r");
$out = fopen(STDOUT, "w");
```

Technically the same, but a little cleaner syntax-wise.

Answer (score 5):

When using fgets, it may block in bash scripts, if the `stdin` isn't set or empty, including while using the `@` [php error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$pipe = @trim(fgets(STDIN));
// Script was called with an empty stdin
// Fail to continue, php warning
```

This behavior can be avoided by setting `stream_set_blocking` on the php header:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, false);
$pipe = @trim(fgets(STDIN));
// Script was called with an empty stdin
// No errors or warnings, continue 
echo $pipe . "!";
```

As example, to be called as follow:

```
echo "Hello world" | ./myPHPscript
// Output "Hello world!"
./myPHPscript
// Output "!"
```

Comment: When using the `declare(strict_types=1);` instruction, it is worth noting that setting the second parameter of `stream_set_blocking` to `0` will cause an error as this function expects its second parameter to be a valid boolean value, when providing an integer. Use `stream_set_blocking(STDIN, false);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually opening STDIN stream, use built in readline() function if you just want to read a single line without too much a hassle :

```
<?php
$age= readline("Enter your age: ");
echo "Your age is : ".$age;
```

PHP documentation is your friend : 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php