# Pass a variable to a PHP script running from the command line

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a PHP file that is needed to be run from the command line (via [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview)). I need to pass `type=daily` to the file, but I don't know how. I tried:

```
php myfile.php?type=daily
```

but this error was returned:

> Could not open input file: myfile.php?type=daily

What can I do?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The `?type=daily` argument (ending up in the `$_GET` array) is only valid for web-accessed pages.

You'll need to call it like `php myfile.php daily` and retrieve that argument from the `$argv` array (which would be `$argv[1]`, since `$argv[0]` would be `myfile.php`).

If the page is used as a webpage as well, there are two options you could consider. Either accessing it with a shell script and [Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget), and call that from [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

```
#!/bin/sh
wget http://location.to/myfile.php?type=daily
```

Or check in the PHP file whether it's called from the command line or not:

```
if (defined('STDIN')) {
  $type = $argv[1];
} else {
  $type = $_GET['type'];
}
```

(Note: You'll probably need/want to check if `$argv` actually contains enough variables and such)

Comment: Recommended way is to use getopt()

Comment: What does defined('STDIN') do?

Answer (score 77):

Just pass it as normal parameters and access it in PHP using the `$argv` array.

```
php myfile.php daily
```

and in myfile.php

```
$type = $argv[1];
```

Comment: Use : if (isset($argv[1])) {
    echo  . $argv[1];
} else {
 die('no ! ');
}

Answer (score 24):

These lines will convert the arguments of a CLI call like `php myfile.php "type=daily&foo=bar"` into the well known `$_GET`-array:

```php
if (!empty($argv[1])) {
    parse_str($argv[1], $_GET);
}
```

Though it is rather messy to overwrite the global `$_GET`-array, it converts all your scripts quickly to accept CLI arguments.

See *[parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)* for details.

---

If you want the more traditional CLI style like `php myfile.php type=daily foo=bar` a small function can convert this into an associative array compatible with a `$_GET`-array:

```php
// Convert $argv into associative array
function parse_argv(array $argv): array
{
    $request = [];
    foreach ($argv as $i => $a) {
        if (!$i) {
            continue;
        }

        if (preg_match('/^-*(.+?)=(.+)$/', $a, $matches)) {
            $request[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        } else {
            $request[$a] = true;
        }
    }

    return $request;
}

if (!empty($argv[1])) {
    $_GET = parse_argv($argv);
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think this is what the OP actually was looking for (running (almost) the same (web) PHP script in a command-line context).

Answer (score 17):

Using the getopt() function, we can also read a parameter from the command line. Just pass a value with the `php` running command:

```
php abc.php --name=xyz
```

#### File *abc.php*

```
$val = getopt(null, ["name:"]);
print_r($val); // Output: ['name' => 'xyz'];
```

Answer (score 6):

Parameters send by index like other applications:

```
php myfile.php type=daily
```

And then you can get them like this:

```
<?php
    if (count($argv) == 0) 
        exit;

    foreach ($argv as $arg)
        echo $arg;
?>
```

Comment: this isn't really that convenient, it doesn't separate out the key and value, it just passes the value "type=daily"

Answer (score 5):

Save this code in file `myfile.php` and run as `php myfile.php type=daily`

```
<?php
$a = $argv;
$b = array();
if (count($a) === 1) exit;
foreach ($a as $key => $arg) {
    if ($key > 0) {
        list($x,$y) = explode('=', $arg);
        $b["$x"] = $y;  
    }
}
?>
```

If you add `var_dump($b);` before the `?>` tag, you will see that the array `$b` contains `type => daily`.

Comment: While this may answer the question, consider adding details on how this solution solves the issue. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Comment: Save this code in file myfile.php and run as 'php myfile.php type=daily'      if you add var_dump($b); before the ?> tag, you will see that the array $b contains type => daily.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code to both work with the command line and a web browser. Put this code above your PHP code. It creates a $_GET variable for each command line parameter.

In your code you only need to check for `$_GET` variables then, not worrying about if the script is called from the web browser or command line.

```
if(isset($argv))
    foreach ($argv as $arg) {
        $e=explode("=",$arg);
        if(count($e)==2)
            $_GET[$e[0]]=$e[1];
        else
            $_GET[$e[0]]=0;
    }
```

Edited. Using this I found a Small bug. If your parameter value contains an = it fails. I'm using this code now:

```
if(isset($argv))
   foreach ($argv as $arg) {
       $e=explode("=",$arg);
       if(count($e)>=2)
           $_GET[$e[0]]=substr($arg,strlen($e[0])+1,strlen($arg));
       else   
           $_GET[$e[0]]=0;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend the use of [getopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php).

If you want help to print out for your options then take a look at *[GetOptionKit](https://github.com/c9s/GetOptionKit#general-command-interface)*.

Comment: Can you elaborate in you answer? E.g., with example code on how to actually do it?

Answer (score 3):

You could [use what sep16 on php.net recommends](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#108883):

```
<?php

parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);

?>
```

It behaves exactly like you'd expect with cgi-php.

```
$ php -f myfile.php type=daily a=1 b[]=2 b[]=3
```

will set `$_GET['type']` to `'daily'`, `$_GET['a']` to `'1'` and `$_GET['b']` to `array('2', '3')`.

Comment: Who or what is "sep16"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The stated author of the post I link to.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it as parameters as follows:

```
php test.php one two three
```

And inside file *test.php*:

```
<?php
    if(isset($argv))
    {
        foreach ($argv as $arg)
        {
            echo $arg;
            echo "\r\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are four main alternatives. Both have their quirks, but **Method 4** has many advantages from my view.

---

`./script` is a [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) starting by `#!/usr/bin/php`

---

**Method 1:** [$argv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

```
./script hello wo8844rld
// $argv[0] = "script", $argv[1] = "hello", $argv[2] = "wo8844rld"
```

⚠️ Using $argv, the parameter order is critical.

---

**Method 2:** [getopt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)

```
./script -p7 -e3
// getopt("p::")["p"] = "7", getopt("e::")["e"] = "3"
```

It's hard to use in conjunction of `$argv`, because:

> ⚠️ The parsing of options will end at the first non-option found,
> anything that follows is discarded.

⚠️ Only 26 parameters as the alphabet.

---

**Method 3:** [Bash Global variable](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-variables)

```
P9="xptdr" ./script
// getenv("P9") = "xptdr"
// $_SERVER["P9"] = "xptdr"
```

Those variables can be used by other programs running in the same shell.

They are blown when the shell is closed, but not when the PHP program is terminated. We can set them permanent in file *~/.bashrc*!

---

**Method 4:** [STDIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) pipe and [stream_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php)

Some piping examples:

---

Feed a string:

```
./script <<< "hello wo8844rld"
// stream_get_contents(STDIN) = "hello wo8844rld"
```

---

Feed a string using bash echo:

```
echo "hello wo8844rld" | ./script
// explode(" ",stream_get_contents(STDIN)) ...
```

---

Feed a file content:

```
./script < ~/folder/Special_params.txt
// explode("\n",stream_get_contents(STDIN)) ...
```

---

Feed an array of values:

```
./script <<< '["array entry","lol"]'
// var_dump( json_decode(trim(stream_get_contents(STDIN))) );
```

---

Feed JSON content from a file:

```
echo params.json | ./script
// json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN)) ...
```

---

It might [work similarly to fread() or fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49109865/2494754), by reading the STDIN.

---

[Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($argv) && is_array($argv)) {
    $param = array();
    for ($x=1; $x<sizeof($argv);$x++) {
        $pattern = '#\/(.+)=(.+)#i';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $argv[$x])) {
            $key =  preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $argv[$x]);
            $val =  preg_replace($pattern, '$2', $argv[$x]);
            $_REQUEST[$key] = $val;
            $$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

I put parameters in $_REQUEST:

```
$_REQUEST[$key] = $val;
```

And it is also usable directly:

```
$$key = $val
```

Use it like this:

```
myFile.php /key=val
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `$$key = $val;`?

Comment: to use directly variable without beeing in a array
extract($_REQUEST) do the job too

Answer (score 0):

I found this [vanilla/garden-cli](https://github.com/vanilla/garden-cli) on github. I think it answers all the needs for PHP CLI.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the complexity of passing to the file, it sounds like you could use sed to insert the line directly into the php file.

sed -i "i (backslash)type=daily myfile.php

```
or as I use it with variables:
```

sed -i "i (backslash)$type = "(backslash)"${daily}(backslash)"(backslash); ${path}"/myfile.php"