# How to get params with shell_exec() in php

Tags: php, cron

I have two php files.

first one execute the second one
I want to send a params with the exec

I have no idea how to get the params i sent in the second file

**first.php:**

```
$params="hello";
shell_exec('php file.php $params > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &')
```

**file.php**:

```
echo $params;
```

Thanks!

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826718/pass-variable-to-php-is-running-from-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array

In your case

```
echo $argv[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$argv` contains any arguments passed to the script.

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo $argv[1]`

Take a look at [this page from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)