# How to pass command line argument to an function in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to pass a string (in command line as, php test.php dad) and check whether its a palindrome or not. I dont know how to pass string argumnet to a function. please explain, sample code is given below,

```
function Palindrome($string){  
    if (strrev($string) == $string){  
        return 1;  
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}  
# I need to pass DAD as an argument in command line
$original = "DAD"; 
if(Palindrome($original)){  
    echo "Palindrome";  
} 
else {  
echo "Not a Palindrome";  
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variable to php script running from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826718/pass-variable-to-php-script-running-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable  [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) . For your case, it's `$argv[1]`