# PHP writing lots of text to STDERR

Tags: php, echo, stdout, stderr

When writing a large chunk to `STDOUT` in PHP you can do this:

```
echo <<<END_OF_STUFF
lots and lots of text
over multiple lines
etc.etc
END_OF_STUFF;
```

(i.e. *heredoc*)

I have the need to do a similar thing but to `STDERR`. Is there another command like `echo` but uses `STDERR` instead?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to do? And what have you tried doing?

Comment: Perhaps this post will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/554775/558021.  Just write to `php://stderr`

Comment: I was hoping for the moral equilivant of `echo` but works on `STDERR` instead.

Comment: An echo is an echo - it all depends where you place it.  You could write your own custom `"error_echo()"` function...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, using php:// stream wrapper: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

```
$stuff = <<<END_OF_STUFF
lots and lots of text
over multiple lines
etc.etc
END_OF_STUFF;

$fh = fopen('php://stderr','a'); //both (a)ppending, and (w)riting will work
fwrite($fh,$stuff);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Instead of the `fopen` stuff I just used `fwrite(STDERR, $stuff);` - Was hoping not to have to create variables all the time.

Comment: You don't need to open the error stream.  [It is already opened and assigned to the constant `STDERR`.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)

Comment: That's correct, but assuming we're in CLI, which is not explicitly given in question :)

Answer (score 24):

For a simple solution - try this

```
file_put_contents('php://stderr', 'This text goes to STDERR',FILE_APPEND);
```

The `FILE_APPEND` parameter will append data and not overwrite it.
You could also write directly to the error stream using the `fopen` and `fwrite` functions.

More info can be found at - http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Comment: One tiny comment: it's good to add LOCK_EX flag like this:

FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX.

Answer (score 2):

In the [CLI SAPI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), it can be as simple as passing a Heredoc string as an argument to `fwrite()` with the STDERR constant.

```
fwrite(STDERR, <<< EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD
);
```