# Getting referrer

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml-rpc

I am running an `xml-rpc` server to share my site's **api** methods.

I want to log all the requests to find out what sites are actually making requests to my `xml-rpc` server.

*Is there any way to do this?*

All I've tried is looking into `$_SERVER` and `$request` variables - nothing inside them.
Thanks.

CI v 2.1.3 in-box xmlrpcs library

Comment: What if read `STD IN` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554760/php-standard-input ?

Comment: Tried top two advises - result is empty