# How to get recursive directory path using inotify-tools in terminal

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu-12.04, inotify, inotifywait

I'm using inotify-tools where i want a notification of file which has been created in recursive directories

Till here i'm succesfull

Now i want to get directory path where a file is been created/dumped in the recursive folders

for e.g abc.txt file is dumped in data/test folder

i want the path to be data/test/abc.txt

Below is the code im using in .sh file

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%f' -e modify -e move -e create -e delete /var/www/cloud/data | while read LINE; 
do 
    php /var/www/cloud/scannner/watcher.php; 
done
```

Kindly please help me to get the path of a dumped file in recursive directories

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%w` modifier:

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' .......
```

To pass the output of inotifywait as an argument to a php script, which will read it for the [`argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) variable you could do this:

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' ....... | while read -r line
do 
    php script.php "$line"
done
```

Otherwise, if you want the php script to read the output of inotifywait from the [standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554760/php-standard-input), then you can just pipe to your script:

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' ....... | php script.php
```

Comment: Thnx user000001...it worked greatly  

Please help me in passing the $line variable to watcher.php file

Comment: @SaideepKankarla added two solutions for that