# Error With Using echo in PHP

Tags: php, console-application

When i use `echo` command in my code to print something to the screen it will add `%` character to the last of word !

but i face this problem only when i run the PHP application using the Linux terminal using the command `php script.php`

The code is

```
<?php
echo "Please Type The Hash : ";
$str = trim(fgets(STDIN,1024));
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: I can confirm it works for me on Linux machine.

Comment: Have you already tried the various solutions from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554760/php-standard-input ?

Comment: You haven't included a linebreak in the output. Are you sure the `%` character is not part of your shell's command prompt?

Comment: In other words, try it with `echo "$str\n";`.

Answer (score 0):

Some shell interpreters (for example ZSH) adds "%" and newline at end of subprocess output to distinguish between output of process and input prompt of shell.

Add a newline to your ouput:

```
echo $str, "\n";
```